# Changing material2 md-toolbar height

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I have one `<md-toolbar>` and I want to change his height.

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">Cards</md-toolbar>
```

I simply tried this in my `component.scss`:

```
md-toolbar {
  height: 50px !important;
  min-height: 50px !important;
}
```

But the text padding goes wrong (space from top is much bigger than the space from the bottom):

[image]

I tried to set the `padding` and `margin` to `0` but it didn't make any changes.

**My questions**

1. How I can adjust the annoying space so the text will be vertically centered perfectly?
2. Any better way to update the `md-toolbar` height?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up adjusting the margin for the container that was below the toolbar to match the height of the toolbar which varied for desktop and mobile as below...

```
.mat-sidenav-container {
  margin-top: 64px;
  @media (max-width: 720px)
  {
    margin-top: 56px;
  }
}
```

Comment: these hard numbers will give perfect result in all resolutions?

Comment: Has done  on Mobile, High Res Desktop, etc.  These hard numbers are same as used in the material component for the height of the navbar although I am not sure about the 720 max-width value I used.  They may a different break point but all tested OK
I used it on this app https://nasa-images.jimclark.net.au/ 
so as that there was no gap or overlap between the toolbar and container when viewing on mobile or desktop, etc

Comment: Got the hard values from here..
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/toolbar/toolbar.scss

Comment: Here is a link to more accurate info on break points for Mobile, etc
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164716/angular-material-toolbar-height-issue

Comment: The max-width value should be 599px. I checked your application, and If you resize the browser window, you can see how  the top margin narrows at 720px of screen width and then recovers its height when you get to extra small width, which is the only size that the toolbar is resized to 56px.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the text should center in the middle vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the flex layout module from Angular :

```
<md-toolbar fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between stretch"></md-toolbar>
```

Comment: It does't make any change to the current view, the text spacing is still wrong

Comment: I did, but it actually don't solve the problem.. the text inside the md toolbar is still in the same position. (My question is about the space of the text inside the toolbar)

Comment: Try setting padding and margin to zero, and all children to height 100%.

Comment: I added `<span>Cards</span>` and set the span `height: 100%; padding-top: 10px` and it did the trick. Not sure if it's ideal but it good enough for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a default predefined row inside the toolbar. You also need to alter that row's height:

```
md-toolbar {
  height:  50px !important;
  min-height: 50px !important;

  md-toolbar-row {
    height: 50px !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't think using !important is a healthy solution. Rather quick fix as one day you will need "!importanter"

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<mat-toolbar>`, you can add in the css file

```
mat-toolbar{
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```